# Add-on sdk : Message passing from contentscript to panel

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

How can I emit an event from content script to panel add-on script and vice versa? And how can I dynamically update the panel content. Please help. An example in this regard will be greatly helpful for beginners. The basic example given [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.0/dev-guide/addon-development/web-content.html) is not working the example is:

```
var panel = require("panel").Panel({
    contentScript: "self.port.emit('showing', 'panel is showing');"
}); 
panel.port.on("showing", function(text) {
    console.log(text);
}); 
panel.show();
```

Nothing is shown in console
This example is given in Add-on SDK tutorial but still it is not working. Any one please Help?

Answer (score 0):

That example works for me.  I see the panel and I see the console.log messages.